# How to update array in Firebase and is this the right way to create one?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I created a code to add `info`s in one array and after this, stores it in the Firebase Database. The result is a numeric id from array. Ex: `0..1..2..3`.

I'm trying to update field `atual` with different value from a `<input>` and got an error. Here's my code to create the array and after this, inserts it in Firebase Database.

```
$scope.addf = function() {
    $scope.lista.push( {
        tipo: $scope.exames.texames.nome,
        maximo: $scope.exames.texames.max,
        minimo: $scope.exames.texames.min,
        atual: '0'
    }); 
    console.log ($scope.lista);


    };

    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.lista.splice(index,1);
    };

    $scope.ok = function() {


        $scope.exame.lista = $scope.lista;                

        $scope.exames.$add($scope.exame).then(function (exameRef) {
          ref.child('exames').child(exameRef.key());
                     toastr.success('Exame adicionado!');
          $state.go('app.exames.list', {}, {reload: true});
        });
      };
```

Here's the code to update the structure:

```
$scope.atualizar = function () {
ref = new Firebase(FBURL);
profiles = ref.child('sexames');
$scope.sexame = $firebaseObject(ref.child('sexames').child($scope.SID.$id));
$scope.sexame.$loaded().then(function(){    

console.log($scope.sexame);
$scope.sexame={
        status: 'Completo',
        lista: { atual: $scope.item.atual}
        } ;



profiles.child($scope.SID.$id).update($scope.sexame, function() {
toastr.success('Usuario Atualizado', {progressBar: true, timeOut: '200'});
});
});
};
```

Comment: here an example but adding one data a need to add more than one

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push